# Dynamic table selection

Tags: t-sql, dynamic, backup

Is it possible to dynamically select a table by name?

For example I have a table, and every time records are uploaded to it a backup is created first with the date appended to the table name.

```
table_20191108
table_20191109
table_20191110
table_20191111
```

What I would like to do is basically write some type of `dynamic sql` that always

`select * from table_MAXDATE`

I would like to do this so I can compare table to the most recent backup (e.g. table_20191111) in order to see what changed between the two tables.

haven't tried anything specific yet.

Comment: Your life would be much easier if you just had a single table with a datetime column.

Comment: This honestly just sounds like a bad idea. If you need versioning there are far better methods; such as having an history table (which stores all the *old* data and their effective dates), having a single table, with the history incldued (active Rows have a `NULL` value for their "Effective To" date), or on newer SQL Server versions Temporal tables. Recreating the table, and archiving it will make your entire database impossible to scale.

Comment: Agreeing with the others here. This is going to be a hard painful road to create this solution on your chosen route. Instead a single table with a datetime column is the right way to go. Whenever you think "Dynamically select a {column, table, schema, database, view, etc}" It's time to rethink your schema.

Comment: Not to pile on, but if your version of SQL Server supports it, this is a textbook example of a reason to implement a [temporal table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Yep. All makes sense. Thanks for the feedback. I will look into switching it to populate an archive table with an Inserted datetime stamp. This was initially implemented by another developer to help us troubleshoot a bug, and was only supposed to be a temporary solution to prevent data loss.

Comment: Nothing is more permanent than a temporary solution :-)